# How to fire find query on sub-documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to get values in a sub-document like the first query below.

```
> db.posts.find({'repository': {'language':'Python'}}).count()
0
> db.posts.find({'actor': 'swiftlinux'}).count()
12
```

Can someone tell me how to get results when the query is based on a sub-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

`db.posts.count({'repository.language': 'Python'})`

Sub-documents are queried with a dot. Also, you apply the count the results of the query, not the result of the `find` method.

Comment: oops i must have guessed it first time :) Thanks

Comment: @Shrey No problem. Please click the checkmark icon next to this answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Oh okay. Sorry about that.